# Want to include a table in a popup

Tags: jquery, html, popup

I have a table created that opens a popup when a cell is clicked on:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Results</h2>
<br/>
<table width="50%" >
<tr><th bgcolor=\'a6d7ed\'><b>Test Group</b></th><th bgcolor=\'a6d7ed\'><b>Pass</b></th><th bgcolor=\'a6d7ed\'><b>Fail</b></th><th bgcolor=\'a6d7ed\'><b>Error</b></th><th bgcolor=\'a6d7ed\'><b>Time</b></th><th bgcolor=\'a6d7ed\'><b>R</b></th>
</tr>
<tr><td>test</td>
<td><a href="#test_Pass" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="fade" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline">10</a></td>
```

Now when I click on 10 I want a table to open in a popup for that value. 
I added the following code to create a popup with the word test in it and it works:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="test_Pass">
   <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
      <h2>Pass testcases from test</h2>
      <p>test</p> 
      <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-left" data-rel="back">Back</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now I wanted a table in the core of the popup so I changed the above code to include a table in the paragraph tag:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="test_Pass">
   <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
      <h2>Pass testcases from test</h2>
         <p><table width="80%" >
         <tr><th bgcolor=\'a6d7ed\'><b>Test</b></th><th bgcolor=\'a6d7ed\'><b>Time</b></th><th bgcolor=\'a6d7ed\'><b>Result</b></th></tr>
         <tr><td>Test: Verifying correct response code is returned</td><td>0.569</td><td bgcolor=\'#00FF40\'></td></tr>
         </table></p>
      <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-left" data-rel="back">Back</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

But both tables now appear on the same page. There is no popup. The only thing I did was replace the popup paragraph text with the table. Can you not do this? Do I need to do something else to get the table into the popup? Any help appreciated

As per request here is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/rqp86v9x/

A

Comment: Can you please provide a JSFiddle?

Comment: thats the exact code. all of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If thats your complete code, then its not working because of syntax errors (unclosed tags). Change it to this:

```
<h2>Results</h2>
<br/>
<table width="50%">
  <tr>
    <th bgcolor=\ 'a6d7ed\'><b>Test Group</b></th>
    <th bgcolor=\ 'a6d7ed\'><b>Pass</b></th>
    <th bgcolor=\ 'a6d7ed\'><b>Fail</b></th>
    <th bgcolor=\ 'a6d7ed\'><b>Error</b></th>
    <th bgcolor=\ 'a6d7ed\'><b>Time</b></th>
    <th bgcolor=\ 'a6d7ed\'><b>R</b></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td><a href="#test_Pass" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="fade" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline">10</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>


<div data-role="popup" id="test_Pass">
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

    <h2>Pass testcases from test</h2>
    <table class='pop' width="80%">
      <tr>
        <th bgcolor=\ 'a6d7ed\'><b>Test</b></th>
        <th bgcolor=\ 'a6d7ed\'><b>Time</b></th>
        <th bgcolor=\ 'a6d7ed\'><b>Result</b></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Test: Verifying correct response code is returned</td>
        <td>0.569</td>
        <td bgcolor=\ 'a6d7ed\'></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-left" data-rel="back">Back</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qjhLm0u1/)

Comment: thank you. I thought I'd closed all tags but I obviously missed some

Comment: More specifically the first `table`'s closing tag and its last `tr`'s closing tag. And you are welcome :)